# Rails sitemap generator uploading to amazon s3 with fog and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, fog, sitemap-generator-gem

I simply cannot get it to work. I am following the tutorial here: https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku

I already have the sitemap working locally, however, now I have followed this tutorial I can neither load up the server nor use sitemap commands without errors.

Error:

```
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)                                 
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                                            
Exiting                                                                                                                                 
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (C:/Users/Callum/Documents/directory/config/environment_variables.ym
l): found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 5 column 22 (Psych::SyntaxError)               
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'                                                  
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'                                                         
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'                                                          
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `block in load_file'                                            
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `open'                                                          
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'                                                     
        from C:/Users/Callum/Documents/directory/config/initializers/environment_variables.rb:7:in `block in <class:Application>'       
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
```

Sitemap.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.uk-franchise.co.uk"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::WaveAdapter.new
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add root_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 1
  add posts_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 1
  add events_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1 
    add industry_accounting_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_agriculture_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_automotive_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_beverage_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_B2B_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_cafeandcoffee_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_care_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_chemical_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_childrenandbabies_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_cleaning_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_communications_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_computers_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_construction_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_consultancy_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_logistics_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_educationandtraining_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_electrical_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_entertainment_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_enviromental_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_estateagents_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_fashion_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_financial_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_food_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_health_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_hirerental_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_hospitality_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_indoorpropertyservices_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_outdoorpropertyservices_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_internet_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_legal_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_manafacture_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_pets_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_promotional_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_print_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    add industry_repairandmaintenance_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
  add industry_investment1_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
  add industry_investment2_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
  add industry_investment3_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
  add industry_investment4_path, :lastmod => Time.now, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
  Post.all.each do |post|
        add post_path(post), :lastmod => post.updated_at, :changefreq => 'monthly', :priority => 1
    end
    Listing.all.each do |listing|
        add listing_path(listing), :lastmod => listing.updated_at, :changefreq => 'yearly', :priority => 1
    end
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines # Not needed if you use the rake tasks
```

Gems

```
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
```

Carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"
  config.storage = :fog
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => ENV["FOG_PROVIDER"],
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
  }
  config.fog_directory = "ukfranchise"
end
```

environmental_variables file

```
development:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: mykey
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: mykey
    FOG_PROVIDER: AWS
    FOG_DIRECTORY: ukfranchise
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, banging my head on the desk atm.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is significant in yaml. In your environment variable file you need to remove the extra level of indentation before the last 3 variables (so that all four variables are at the same level of indentation under the development key). I think that should at least get you past the issue you are seeing above.